# How can i use this jquery plugin for gridview instead of table

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Hi all i would like to work out this functionality for grdiveiw instead of table can any one guide me please.

http://fixedheadertable.com/

I tried this by registering the required scripts but didn't work for me so can any one help  me

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdEarnings" runat="server" CssClass="myTable01" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#DEE6F7" ShowHeader="true" Font-Size="11pt">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="ID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="<%#ID %>"></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRegular" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="Price">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="Description">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

The other one i tried works fine for me but as i am using tool tips in my application i included some scripts related to that when i include that i am unable to view the scroll bar for grid view

> Untitled Page
>
> ```
> <script src="Scripts/ScrollableGridPlugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
>
> <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () {
> $('#<%=grdEarnings.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
>     ScrollHeight: 300
> });
>  });
> </script>
>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
>  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```

if i commented the scripts that were after the `Jquery` function this works well enough for me. But while running along with those scripts i am unable to view the scroll bar for gridview

Answer (score 1):

You need to first include jQuery and then your jQuery plugin (ScrollableGridPlugin). Moreover I don't understand why you have multiple jQuery includes with different versions (1.4.2, 1.4.4, 1.3.2)?

Whether the jQuery ScrollableGridPlugin works with an ASP GridView rather than with a normal table depends on the HTML which is generated by the GridView.

(Moreover, shouldn't the call be `$('selector').fixedHeaderTable({ footer: false, cloneHeadToFoot: true, fixedColumn: false });` according to the docs [you provided?](http://fixedheadertable.com/))

Comment: Hi `Juri` thanks for ur reply why i am using different versions is as per the code that i got from my search as per my requirement i used that some for `tooltip` some for `Calendar` like that

Comment: Sure, you should only reference one jQuery library. Possibly your tooltip and calendar plugins still work with a newer jQuery lib as it _should_ be backwards compatible :)

Answer (score 0):

For the FixedHeaderTable plugin usage you need to add a `thead` element to grdidview and move the very first gridview's row into it:

```
$(function () {
     var gridView = $("#<%= grdEarnings.ClientID %>");
     gridView.prepend( $("<thead></thead>").append( gridView.find("tr:first") ) );

     gridView.fixedHeaderTable({ height: '300' });
});
```

Comment: But when having multiple scrips the scroll bar is not showing

Comment: remove redundant jquery script references - left only one for the most recent jquery library version.